# Possible to automate an excel process using java?

Tags: java, excel, selenium

My current program is trying to download files and then combine them into one large excel file.  The issue that I'm struggling with is that the website I'm downloading them from is for some reason making them .html files, but appending the .xls extension to them.  This allows them to be opened by Excel manually but does not allow me to use Apache POI in order to read them as it sees a file format/extension difference.  My process is as follows:

1 - Run part of my program which downloads a file through my web browser using Selenium - This works fine

2 - Manually open each downloaded file and Save-As xlsx files (Note: When I open them in Excel manually is when I'm told there is a file format/extension difference just to be clear)

3 - Run the rest of my program which combs through each new file (the ones created in step 2) and appends all the data to the ultimate output file - This works fine

Is there any way to automate the process or am I going to have to continue to do it manually?

Comment: Sounds like your files are not _really_ in excel format, but rather HTMLs that probably contain some tables which MS-Excel can parse. What do you see when you open such a file with a regular text editor like Notepad++?

Comment: It shows me all the HTML from the page originally

Answer (score 0):

you said in the comment that you opened the file in text editor and saw that it is HTML5.

I would use HTML parser like jsoup to get the data that you need and create a new file using Apache POI.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [EasyXLS](https://www.easyxls.com) library. It allows to read HTML files and save as XLSX.

```
ExcelDocument workbookForXLSX = new ExcelDocument();

for (int i=0; i<fileCount; i++){
   ExcelDocument workbookForHTML = new ExcelDocument();
   workbookForHTML.easy_LoadHTMLFile(filePath[i]);//or stream to the file
   workbookForXLSX.easy_addWorksheet((ExcelWorksheet)workbookForHTML.easy_getSheetAt(0));
   workbookForHTML.Dispose();
}

workbookForXLSX.easy_WriteXLSXFile(filePathXLSX);
workbookForXLSX.Dispose();
```

You can download the Excel library for Java from:
https://www.easyxls.com/java-excel-library

More details about reading HTML files and what HTML tags are supported at:
https://www.easyxls.com/manual/basics/import-from-html-file-format.html